# Writing multiple sentences on one line

Tags: vb.net

I want my program to write the following to to the console:

> The volume of your Right Rectangular Prism is: *** Cm^3

But I don't know how to make it write anything after I specify the "& volume" in the call to the `WriteLine` method.  Is there any way to actually do this?

Here is my code for that line:

```
Console.Write("The volume of your right rectangular prism is: " & volume):("Cm^3")
```

Comment: Just continue the concatenation. 
Console.Write("The volume of your right rectangular prism is: " & volume & " Cm^3");

Comment: Also ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/te2585xw.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
Console.Write("The volume of your right rectangular prism is: " & volume & " whatever else you want to say")
```

In fact you could keep going... the basic concept is end your text then do a  `&`, then add the variable. If you need more you can always repeat it the same way.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a line of C#?

You can use something like:

```cs
Console.Write("The volume of your right rectangular prism is: ");
Console.WriteLine(volume & " Cm^3");
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for things like this:

```
String.Format("The volume of the sphere with radius {0} is {1}", radius, volume)
```

You can put this inside your `Console.WriteLine`, or save it to another variable first if you want to keep the line from getting too long.

Comment: As do I, since you can provide numeric formatting for each argument inline i.e. `"...radius {0:0.0} mm is {1:0.000} ml."`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your code is invalid.  The following portion is wrong:

```
volume):("Cm^3")
```

The first closing parentheses ends the call to the `Write` method.  The colon is used in VB.NET to separate two statements on the same line, much like the semicolon is used in C#, and other similar languages.  However, the next statement, after the colon, is invalid.  `("Cm^3")` is, all on its own, an invalid statement.  It looks like you are specifying parameters to a method without ever specifying which method you are trying to call.  I suspect that what you meant to do was something like this:

```
Console.Write("The volume of your right rectangular prism is: " & volume) : Console.Write("Cm^3")
```

That will work, but it's a bit unusual.  Typically, in VB.NET, you'd just put each statement on its own line, like this:

```
Console.Write("The volume of your right rectangular prism is: " & volume)
Console.Write("Cm^3")
```

However, rather than using concatenation, at that point, you could just call `Write` three times, like this:

```
Console.Write("The volume of your right rectangular prism is: ")
Console.Write(volume)
Console.Write("Cm^3")
```

Or, you could concatenate all three together in a single call to the `Write` method, like this:

```
Console.Write("The volume of your right rectangular prism is: " & volume & "Cm^3")
```

Or, another popular option is to use the string formatting feature like this:

```
Console.Write("The volume of your right rectangular prism is: {0}Cm^3", volume)
```